# Drag and drop pdf file to Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I created ListBox with drop handler like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbFile" AllowDrop="True" Drop="DropHere" />
```

But when I try move file from desktop to Silverlight the drop event never occurs, because web browser (Internet Explorer, Mozilla etc) opens pdf in card where was Silverlight.

The question is, how I can handle drag-and-drop file from computer to Silverlight or how to prevent opening file in web browser.

I presented this situation at the following printscreen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9ZzW.png

Comment: You cannot, drag'n'drop is for controls inside your Silverlight app.

Comment: bad news.. but thanks for your help. Do you have any other idea how to handle drag-and-drop file to Silverlight?

Comment: you can simulate it with a bit of javascript and a file uploader.

Answer (score 1):

You can Drag and drop from desktop in a silverlight application. Check "Require Elevated permissions" in silverlight project properties and using drop event of silverlight datagrid one can handle the drag and drop from desktop in a silverlight datagrid.

```
  private void DocumentsDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
  {
    e.Handled = true;

    var point = e.GetPosition(null);
    var dataGridRow = ExtractDataGridRow(point);
    if(dataGridRow !=null)
    {.....
     }

    var droppedItems = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as      FileInfo[];
    if (droppedItems != null)
         {
            var droppedDocumentsList = new List<FileInfo>();

            foreach (var droppedItem in droppedItems)
            {
                if ((droppedItem.Attributes & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
                {
                    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(droppedItem.FullName);
                    droppedDocumentsList.AddRange(directory.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
                }
                else
                {
                    droppedDocumentsList.Add(droppedItem);
                }
            }

            if (droppedDocumentsList.Any())
            {
                ProcessFiles(droppedDocumentsList);
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayErrorMessage("The selected folder is empty.");
            }
        }
     }
```

Set AllowDrop =true; in xaml for the datagrid. From the DragEventArgs extract the information as FileInfo Object.